# Create variables from unknown number of fields in PHP

Tags: php, foreach

I have a dynamic form that has the following field.

```
<input class="uk-input" id="Employer1Name" name="EmployerName[]" type="text" placeholder="">
```

The user can add as many as they need using a button which increments the id dynamically to keep them unique, for example:

```
    <input class="uk-input" id="Employer1Name" name="EmployerName[]" type="text" placeholder="">   
    <input class="uk-input" id="Employer2Name" name="EmployerName[]" type="text" placeholder="">
    <input class="uk-input" id="Employer3Name" name="EmployerName[]" type="text" placeholder="">
```

I won't know how many they include but I need to take this into PHP and get it into a table. I use JQuery Serialize and Ajax to get the data to the PHP script. Do I create a new variable for each item? If so how? I have:

```
foreach($_POST['EmployerName'] as $key => $value) {
    echo $key." - ".$value;

}
```

This loops over all 'EmployerName' to get the key and value but I need to then process these into a MySQL statement into a database. I just don't know how to go about getting the data out of the loop, I am thinking of creating variables for each such as `$EmployerName.$key = $value`, but I get stuck with "Undefined variable: EmployerName in ..."

*edit

1. I can use $value to get the value but how do I associate that with a variable to use later?
2. There is much more data so doing anything in the loop will cause issues with other variables being looped over that only occur once.

Comment: You could just use `$_POST['EmployerName'][0]`, `$_POST['EmployerName'][1]` etc.

Comment: Please explain the issue you have. Why can't `$value` be used?

Comment: Just call you DB query inside the loop. You don't need to call the query outside the loop. Just do the stuff inside the loop. The input is an array. You can so what you want with that array of input data.

Comment: ^^ or if that doesn't work explain why, and show code related to the issue

Comment: there is no need to create new variables for each value, but if that is what you want to do the correct syntax that you were looking for above would be `${'EmployerName'.$key} = $value`

Comment: @Nathanael, why is that? How could I 'INSERT INTO' a database if I don't have a variable name or know how many employers were sent from the form? Not sure my brain is working today.

Comment: @Eric.18 I cannot answer your question with only a vague description of what you are doing, but in general it is much easier to work with arrays than scattered variables

Comment: In the first comment here I showed you what you could use in the query. You can use that without having to loop or do anything else.

Comment: @JayBlanchard, hmm, I see that but how will I know if it is only $_POST['EmployerName'][0] or $_POST['EmployerName'][18] without a loop?

Comment: Never just send $_POST data directly without handling it into the database! Always check user input!! Even if you trust your users or know them. See my answer to see how you can get the data "out" of the loop and use it later on for your database operation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with @Nathanael, the correct way to associate the value with a new variable would be

```php
${'EmployerName'.$key} = $value
```

But the values are already accessible with `$_POST['EmployerName'][$i]` where `$i` is the index, and you can get the total values count with `count($_POST['EmployerName'])`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store your data for later use you can do the following:

```
<?php

$newArray = array();

foreach($_POST['EmployerName'] as $key => $value) {
    $newArray[$key] = $value;
}

die('<pre>' . print_r($newArray, true) . '</pre>');
```

Of course you can build your $newArray they way you need. For example with the other data you mentioned. Make sure you handle the user input and use PDO for your database operations later on.

Let me know if you have any other question

Working example: https://ideone.com/qPcG80